# Add Tag to ComboBox Items From Model

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a `TypeOfContact` model that is made up of an ID, and Text. For example, one type would be `Telephone` and the ID would be `1`. Another type would be `Email` and the ID `2`.

What I would like to do is add the text of the `TypeOfContact` as an item and the `ID` as a tag. I imagine it would look something like this, however this isn't working;

```
contactTypeComboBox.Items.Clear();
foreach (TypeOfContact c in ContactTypes)
{
    contactTypeComboBox.Items.Add(c.ContactTypeText);

    foreach (ComboBoxItem item in contactTypeComboBox.Items)
    {
        item.Tag = c.ContactTypeID;
    }
}
```

The reason I want to do this is that when someone selects one of the `ComboBox` items I want to store the text and the ID. I could do this all through XAML but `ContactTypes` is  a list that is populated by the user, so I cannot hard code the values into the `ComboBox` as maintaining it and adding new `TypesOfContact` would be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue myself by first adding;

`DisplayMemberPath="ContactTypeText" SelectedValuePath="ContactTypeID"`

to the `XAML` of the `ComboBox` then accessing the ID like;

`contactTypeComboBox.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

In your situation i would bind the list of your TypeOfContacts as ItemsSource to the ComboBox. After that you could set the tag, but i think you don't will need it, because when you also bind the SelectedItem you got back the whole item (ID, type, ...) and can work with it in other parts of your code.

Example for simplifying without a ViewModel (but you should use one):

**Codebehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        FillListWithSomeExamples();
    }

    private void FillListWithSomeExamples()
    {
        TypesOfContacts.Add(new TypesOfContact {Id = 1, Type = "Email"});
        TypesOfContacts.Add(new TypesOfContact { Id = 2, Type = "Telephone" });
    }

    public TypesOfContact SelectedTypesOfContact { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TypesOfContact> TypesOfContacts { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TypesOfContact>();
}
```

TheTestmodel:

```
public class TypesOfContact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TypesOfContacts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTypesOfContact}" DisplayMemberPath="Type"/>
</Grid>
```

Now you can read the selected item in any other method of the MainWindow by looking at SelectedTypesOfContact.